# Stack Exchange Private Beta features

Tags: support, stack-exchange

In [Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange) is shown the list of the recent feature changes to Stack Exchange.

Is there a list with the features SE sites started with in **Private Beta**? I mean, before adding all these features.

Comment: Do you mean the original feature list on Stack Overflow before other sites were created?

Comment: @Anna Yes, that's what I mean.

Answer (score 3):

The original stackoverflow site:

- has no comments
- no bounties
- no tag wiki's
- no inboxes (global or other)
- no moderator tools
- no tag specific badges
- no votes to close (with enough rep you could close a question)
- no faq (alhough there where questions with the faq tag.
- no meta site
- no chat
- no penalty box
- no vote fraud detection
- no flag weight

There were:

- questions
- answers
- up and downvotes
- some ways to close a question
- you could delete unwanted comments from your question
- you could flag a question or answer, and with 5 flags the question was deleted and the owner lost 100 rep.
- you could mark your posts as community wiki (and there was a lot of discussion about that).
- uservoice for the bug and feature requests

I have probably forgotten some, but as you can see, there have been a lot of changes from the big bang.

Comment: You say there were no comments, then you say you could delete comments?

Answer (score 2):

The list of recent changes is valid not only for Stack Overflow, but also for other Stack Exchange sites, including the ones in beta phase.
The changes are first applied to Meta Stack Overflow, then to Stack Overflow, and to the other SE sites.

There can be some differences between Stack Overflow, and the other SE sites, but (as far as I can see) those differences are not reported in the page you linked. For example, on Stack Overflow the number of closing votes you have (if you have the privilege of voting to close questions) are 50, while in other SE sites you have 24 votes to close questions.

There is not a list of the original features Stack Overflow implemented.